# Как поместить результаты работы парсера во фрагменты?

Tags: android, json, activity

Здравствуйте, сообщество Stackoverflow!
Недавно начал изучать программирование под Андроид и столкнулся с такой проблемой.
Не могу понять как результаты работы парсера поместить в нужные мне фрагменты.

Имеется такой парсер json:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    // Declare Variables
    JSONObject jsonobject;
    JSONArray jsonarray;
    ListView listview;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
    static String TITLE = "title";
    static String SHORT_STORY = "short_story";
    static String CENA = "cena";
    static String SKIDKA = "skidka";
    static String CATEGORY = "category";
    static String IMAGE = "image";




    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the view from listview_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);
        // Execute DownloadJSON AsyncTask
        new DownloadJSON().execute();
    }




    // DownloadJSON AsyncTask
    private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a progressdialog
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            // Set progressdialog title
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Android JSON Parse Tutorial");
            // Set progressdialog message
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // Show progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Create an array
            arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
            jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://raccoon-media.ru/json.json");

            try {
                // Locate the array name in JSON
                jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("prod");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Retrive JSON Objects
                    map.put("title", jsonobject.getString("title"));
                    map.put("short_story", jsonobject.getString("short_story"));
                    map.put("cena", jsonobject.getString("cena"));
                    map.put("skidka", jsonobject.getString("skidka"));
                    map.put("image", jsonobject.getString("image"));
                    map.put("category", jsonobject.getString("category"));
                    // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                    arraylist.add(map);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
            listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
            // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
            adapter = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, arraylist);
            // Set the adapter to the ListView
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            // Close the progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu;
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }



}
```

И имеется главная активити (сделанная как описано здесь http://habrahabr.ru/post/236567/) с вкладками через SlidingTabLayout и SlidingTabStrip, где каждая вкладка это фрагмент.

Как результаты этого парсера запихнуть в одну из вкладок, другого парсера - в другую вкладку и т.д. ?

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Выходит что каждая из вкладок - это отдельный фрагмент, поэтому создавайте класс, наследник Fragment, и в нем уже обрабатывайте работу с данными. А потом можно обращаться к активити для вывода данных или каких то других задач. Взгляните пример тут - http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/176-urok-106-android-3-fragments-vzaimodejstvie-s-activity

Comment: Есть нечто похожее на решение моей проблемы https://toster.ru/q/124725
Но в нужный мне фрагмент всё равно ничего не выводится.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение простое.

Во фрагменте, внутри `onViewCreated`:
просто выполнить нужную функцию вот так:

```
new DownloadJSON().execute();
```

Перед этим весь код этой функции поместить вместе с кодом фрагмента, но изменить 
`MainActivity.this` (в 2-х местах) - на `getActivity()`.

Но появилась другая проблема:
Как сделать чтобы `new DownloadJSON().execute()` выполнялся только один раз? 
Сейчас он выполняется каждый раз при вызове фрагмента.

Comment: "Другую проблему" опубликуйте, пожалуйста, отдельным вопросом.

Answer (score 2):

Для коммуникаций между фрагментом и активити можно использовать:

1. Передачу данных через `Bundle` методами `setArguments()` - отправить из активити и `getArguments()` - получить в фрагменте.
2. Реализовать собственный интерфейс для передачи данных.
3. Отправить `LocalBroadcast`.
4. Использовать сторонние библиотеки для коммуникаций, например `EventBus`.
5. Использовать прямой доступ через методы в фрагменте.
6. В последнее время все чаще упоминается [реактивное программирование](http://habrahabr.ru/company/2gis/blog/228125/) для взаимодействия частей приложения , что в мире Java наиболее полно представлено в виде библиотеки `RxJava`.

Так как ваш вопрос слишком широк для более детального ответа, то указал только направления для решений. Писать все эти реализации в коде можно долго и это очень скучно.

К тому же, обо всех этих способах уже очень много написано, в том числе и на этом ресурсе. Я в своей практике, с недавних пор, использую `EventBus` для всех коммуникаций между частями приложения, как наиболее гибкий и универсальный инструмент. Планирую как то разобраться с RxJava, по многочисленным отзывам технология более перспективная.

Comment: Моя вина. Не смог грамотно сформулировать вопрос. Не могу понять как запихнуть результаты работы парсера в нужные мне фрагменты?

Comment: Немного выше вы можете прочитать шесть вариантов, как это можно сделать